# About numpy's concatenate, hstack, vstack functions?

Tags: python, numpy

See some examples

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
b = np.array([4, 5, 6])
print(np.concatenate((a,b), axis=0)) # [1,2,3,4,5,6]
print(np.hstack((a,b))) # [1,2,3,4,5,6]

print(np.vstack((a,b))) # [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
print(np.concatenate((a,b), axis=1)) # IndexError: axis 1 out of bounds [0, 1)
```

The result of hstack is the same as concatenate along axis=0, but the api document says hstack=concatenate along axis=1, please look at the https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html#numpy.hstack

And concatenating along the axis=1 raise an IndexError, the api document says hstack=concatenate along axis=0, please look at the https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html#numpy.vstack

Can anybody explain it?By the way, can anybody explain how to broadcast when the ndarray's dimension is less than 2 and concatenating along axis=1?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35401041/concatenation-of-2-1d-numpy-arrays-along-2nd-axis

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenation of 2 1D numpy arrays along 2nd axis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35401041/concatenation-of-2-1d-numpy-arrays-along-2nd-axis)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the actual code for `hstack`:

```
arrs = [atleast_1d(_m) for _m in tup]
# As a special case, dimension 0 of 1-dimensional arrays is "horizontal"
if arrs[0].ndim == 1:
    return _nx.concatenate(arrs, 0)
else:
    return _nx.concatenate(arrs, 1)
```

I don't see anything in the docs about `axis=1`.  The term it uses is `'stack them horizontally'`.

As I noted a year ago, [Concatenation of 2 1D numpy arrays along 2nd axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35401041/concatenation-of-2-1d-numpy-arrays-along-2nd-axis), earlier versions don't raise an error if the axis is too high.  But in 1.12 we get an error.

There is a newish `np.stack` that can add a dimension where needed:

```
In [46]: np.stack((np.arange(3), np.arange(4,7)),axis=1)
Out[46]: 
array([[0, 4],
       [1, 5],
       [2, 6]])
```

The base function is `concatenate`.  The various `stack` functions adjust array dimensions in one way or other, and then do `concatenate`.  Look at their code to see the details.  (I've summarized the differences in earlier posts as well).

Comment: The "Notes" section of the documentation states that `hstack` is "Equivalent to np.concatenate(tup, axis=1)".

Comment: Missed that.  But short notes like that should be taken with a big 'grain of salt'.

Comment: After looking at  the source code, I can understand, thanks. May it is an oversight of the api document.

Answer (score 0):

`np.hstack(tup)` and `np.concatenate(tup, axis=1)` are indeed equivalent but only if `tup` contains arrays that are at least 2-dimensional. This was in fact spelled out in the documentation for `vstack`, so it looks like it was just an oversight that it did not also in the documentation for `hstack`; it will [for future versions](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/commit/b7dc5193f7136f5b09f45c3fb10118556e961e74) though.

Comment: You may change the dstack's NOTES, ' at least 3-dimensional', https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html#numpy.dstack

Comment: I agree; added a PR for that one as well.